# regexp_replace fails in presto but works on regex101 with java8 flavor

Tags: java, regex, presto

The following regex works on regex101 (with the Java8 flavor), but doesn't work when running it with regexp_replace in Presto SQL.

Regex:
`(?<!timeFrame:\"(?:\d\d?\d?\d?)?)[0-9.\/,]`

Test string:
`timeFrame:"122 Days" ipAddress:1.1.1.1`

Expected outcome:
`timeFrame:"122 Days" ipAddress:`

You can see it working on regex101 here:
https://regex101.com/r/udpivA/1

According to [Presto's documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html), it should be running "the Java pattern syntax".

When running this function in Presto:
`regexp_replace(string, '(?<!timeFrame:\"(?:\d\d?\d?\d?)?)[0-9.\/,]', '')`

I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: invalid pattern in look-behind
```

How can I get this regex to work on Presto?

Comment: Maybe it is the `?` quantifier, older versions should only allow limiting quantifiers, try `(?<!timeFrame:\"(?:\d{1,4}){0,1})[0-9./,]`

Comment: Thanks! I still get the same error with this pattern..

Comment: Ok, why do you try the negation approach if you just want to remove the IP after `ipAddress`?  Use `(ipAddress:)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}` and replace with `$1`. `regexp_replace(string, '(ipAddress:)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}', '$1')`

Comment: This is just one particular example, I have a lot of variations in this dataset. My Regex needs to remove any of these characters [0-9./,], unless it comes right after this string: 'timeFrame:\'

Comment: Then you will have to unwrap the pattern, `regexp_replace(string, '(?<!timeFrame:\")(?<!timeFrame:\"\d)(?<!timeFrame:\"\d\d)(?<!timeFrame:\"\d\d\d)(?<!timeFrame:\"\d\d\d\d)[0-9./,]', '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message mentions an invalid pattern in the look-behind pattern, which most probably means that presto does not support look-behind patterns that could match strings with *varying* lengths, and so it would not allow the `?` quantifier (nor `+` or `*`) in a look-behind pattern.

You can avoid this by actually matching the "timeframe" pattern, and capturing it in a capture group, so that you can *reproduce* it in the replacement string with `$1` -- which practically means that you *don't* actually delete it. With `|` you can then add another alternative that also matches digits (but which don't match with the first option). If those are matched, the capture group (around the "timeframe" pattern) is empty, and so `$1` represents the empty string, which practically means that those matches are *removed*:

```
regexp_replace(string, '(timeFrame:\"\d+)|\d[0-9.\/,]*', '$1')
```

NB: I have prefixed the `[0-9.\/,]` pattern with `\d` as I assume you don't want to remove points and commas when they are not part of a term that starts with a digit.